# How to get multiple lines in a variable in For loop from bacth file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to get All task scheduler name fetched from below *query* :

**UPDATE** : Adding the *code* I have tried so far:

```
@echo off
echo TaskName, NextRunTime, Status 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims="  %%a in ('schtasks /query /fo list^|findstr /b "TaskName*"') do (
set Task=%%~a
set Task=!Task: =!
set Task=!Task:"=!
set Task=!Task:TaskName:=!
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('schtasks /query /fo list^|findstr /b "Next Run Time*"') do (
set Run=%%~b
set Run=!Run: =!
set Run=!Run:"=!
set Run=!Run:NextRunTime:=!
 )
 for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('schtasks /query /fo list^|findstr /b "Status*"') do (
set Sta=%%~c
set Sta=!Sta: =!
set Sta=!Sta:"=!
set Sta=!Sta:Status:=!
)
echo !Task!,!Run!,!Sta!
```

But instead if all the task it returns only **1 task**. I believe, it just read 1st line of the string and returned the same and skipped all the others.

How can I fetch all the task names with this?

Comment: You are getting the last task from the query.  Not sure why you are trying to remove spaces from your task name.  Tasks can have spaces in the names.  You would be better off use the CSV format option.

Comment: This is purpose of ITRS monitoring setup, where i just need TaskName(not with Keyword "TaskName") Status and RunWindow, in 3 columns respectively, Omitting the spaces is not an issue, but if i can get all the tasks, that may help me with my purpose

Comment: Run Window is not a field name.

Comment: Next Run Time is the name of the field

Comment: Like I said in my first comment.  Use the CSV  format. `schtasks /query /fo csv |find /i /v "taskname"`

Comment: sorry, your script doesn't return *anything*. Where is the `echo`? If it's *after*  the `)`, it should return just one task (the last one), if it's *before*  the `)`, all tasks are shown.

Comment: echo is after the ")", this is the issue i am facing,  how can i get all task if echo is defined outside of ")"

Comment: Why? (While setting a multi-line variable is possible with some tricks, it isn't a good idea. Batch variables have a limit (max length), output of `schtasks /query` surely is much longer.)

Comment: I've included whole bat file, this may give an idea, how i want my bat to return the result, all tasks,NextRunTime,Status needs to separate by comma(,), and    echo !Task!,!Run!,!Sta! should contain whole task and their status

Comment: Are you purposely ignoring my code examples I gave you.  It does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Squashman i was not ignoring your code, i have tried this approach but i am getting all Task headings which i do not want, i have tried CSV /NH, but seems it's not working with Windows 2008R2, that is why this approach is not feasible until i can get rid off the headers(in this case, TaskName, Next Run Time and Status)

Comment: In this code: `schtasks /query /fo csv |find /i /v "taskname"`, the find command is getting removing the header records.  Plain and simple.  Just copy and paste that single line of code into a cmd prompt.  It is the same code that @Stephan is using in his answer below except he is using the `FINDSTR` command to make sure it matches at the beginning of the line.  Been doing this for a couple of decades and I assume Stephan has as well so you should probably figure out what the error is on your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squashman's comment shows you how to do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "delims="  %%a in ('schtasks /query /fo csv^|findstr /vb "TaskName"') do (
  echo %%a
)
```

or if you don't want the quotes:

```
...
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=,"  %%a in ('schtasks /query /fo csv^|findstr /vb "TaskName"') do (
  echo %%~a,%%~b,%%~c
)
```

Comment: I think you have to escape the quotes to match them `findstr /vb \"TaskName\"`